# Does the Oracle DB listener bind to private ip address only?

Tags: database, oracle, amazon-ec2, oracle11g, listener

When the Oracle Database Listener service is configured after DB installation, does it bind or depend on the private IP address only?
Would it work or start as a service with the public IP address configured to it.
For Cloud instances, the private IP keeps changing & due to this, the listener service does not start with new changed IP addresses.

Comment: I believe you specify a host name, not a specific IP ( [listener docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28316/listenercfg.htm#i454523) )

Comment: I think you can do both... if you use a hostname you should have the dns resolution setup in your local host file probably (no so sure about these things, I'm trying to give ideas)

Comment: Hi tbone, as you've said, the OracleDB listener does work mainly with the hostname. @Sebas the local host file is used to associate hostnames with their corresponding IP addresses, this allows you to connect to a server with it's host name rather than just it's IP address. The DB listener does not have any specific setting with the local host file in the above mentioned scenario.

Comment: A helpful link: https://community.oracle.com/thread/852312

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to configure Oracle Listener with hostname, in case your dns server resolves ip addresses correctly you should have no problem accessing Oracle with hostname.

As for public ip address access, after configuring Oracle with hostname your network's router should be configured to forward a port to Oracle Listener hostname:port. Then you will be able to access Oracle publicly. Of course firewall configuration should be done accordingly.

Comment: Hi brhneser, i've managed to get the Oracle DB configured & working with the Hostname. Like you said, the DNS server should be resolved correctly with the IP. This however, needs to be added to config files in Oracle's DB 'app' directory after installation. It binds with one IP during installation & does not work if this IP changes afterwards. But it's working properly now with the hostname.

Comment: Well, not really. changing listener definition in listener.ora should do the trick. For example if listener is called listener LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC0))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <host_name>)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )